# Consuming REST using Angularjs with spring boot

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

```
$http.get("http://localhost:port/angular").success(function (response){
    alert('in success method');
      $scope.returnValue = response;
  }).error(function(data, status) {
    alert('in ERROR method');
   });
```

Above is my controller

and my spring rest service

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/angular",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String getRestAngular(){
        return "abcd";
    }
```

when I call external links eg:http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting .It is working fine.

But when i call my local rest service angular goes into error block

Comment: Have you checked what the error actually is?

Comment: response is not defined

Comment: What does that mean? Is it a client side error? Server side? You said angular goes to your error callback, but there is no "response" there.

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting with correct REST endpoint? Check on e.g. Firebug if you are requesting to the server. I'm not sure if Angular does something with your connection URL, but `"http://localhost:port/angular"` does not seem to look proper - port should be defined.

Comment: Yeah port is 8080. Just for an example i showed that

Comment: I implemented the src/main/java/hello/SimpleCORSFilter.java after which i could do GET calls. But now im stuck with post

I used SimpleCROSFilter.java from the following
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/